# Sklearn GaussianMixture

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, handwriting-recognition, mixture

I have been learning for myself for several months artificial intelligence through a project of character recognition and transcription of handwriting. Until now I have successfully used Keras, Theano and Tensorflow by implementing CNN, CTC neural networks.

Today, I try to use Gaussian mixture models, the first step towards hidden markov models with  Gaussian emission. To do so, I used the sklearn mixture with pca reduction to select the best model with Akaike and Bayesian information criterion. With type of covariance Full for Aic which provides a nice U-curve and Tied for Bic, because with Full covariance Bic gives just a linear curve. With 12.000 samples, I get the best model at 60 n-components for Aic and 120 n-components for Bic.

My input images have 64 pixels aside which represent only the capital letters of the English alphabet, 26 categories numbered from 0 to 25.

The fit method of Sklearn GaussianMixture ignore labels and the predict method returns the position of the component (0 to 59 or 0 to 119) into the n-components regarding the probabilities.

How to retrieve the original label the position of the character in a list using sklearn GaussianMixture ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to use GaussianMixture in a generative classifier. You need to compute P(Y|X) for each label and estimate label according to these probabilities. To do so, you need to keep a GMM for each label and train with data from corresponding label. Then score method will give you likelihood, P(X|Y), of given data (or log-likelihood, you may want to check that). If you multiple likelihood with prior, you get posterior, P(Y|X). For each label, you will get a posterior e.g. P(Y=0|X), P(Y=1|X), ... Label with the maximum posterior probability can be reported as estimated label.

You can get some hints from the code sample below. (Here it is assumed that prior probabilities are equal, you need to consider that in your implementation)

```
Y_predicted = clf.predict(X_test)

score = np.empty((Y_test.shape[0], 10))
predictor_list = []
for i in range(10):
  predictor = GMM()
  predictor.fit(X[Y==i])
  predictor_list.append(predictor)
  score[:, i] = predictor.score(X_test)

Y_predicted = np.argmax(score, axis=1)
```